# How do I fit text into footer margins

Tags: html, css, margin, footer

I know this is probably very simple for most of you but it's kicking my butt. I am building my business's website using Dreamweaver CS6 to edit a template I downloaded from free website templates. The problem that I'm having is that I can't fit the link on the right side of the footer into the footer. I'm not sure if this is an HTML problem or a CSS problem. Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

Left Margin.........Right Margin

Home...About...Gallery...Contacts

It doesn't seem to matter how many links are there, the last one overhangs the footer. I'd appreciate any help you can give me. Thank you.

http://tinypic.com/r/2nvcljq/6

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BRANIS/dABzc/)

```
#footer ul.navigation {
float: right;
display: inline-block;
line-height: 24px;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#footer ul.navigation li {
float: left;
margin-left: 15px;
}
#footer ul.navigation li:first-child {
margin-left: 0;
}
#footer ul.navigation li a {
color: #ab7d0f;
font: 11px/24px "Oswald";
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
#footer ul.navigation li a:hover {
color: #241b18;
}
#footer #footnote {
color: #ab7d0f;
font: 11px/24px "Oswald";
margin: 0;
text-transform: uppercase;
}


<div id="footer">
    <div>
      <div id="links">
        <div class="showroom">

              <p>4885 Wilson Street<br> Victorville, CA 92392<br><br> 702-409-5373<br>
                <br> 
                  <a href="index.html">info@briarpatchfurniture.com</a>
          </p>
          </div>

        <ul class="navigation">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
                <a href="about.html">About</a><a href="gallery.html"> Gallery</a>
              <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <p id="footnote">
            © Copyright TIBISI, Inc 2013. All Rights Reserved.
      </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't figure out how to add a screenshot.

Comment: As i see in chrome it works well. In which browser you see this behavior?

Comment: Is there a way for me to add a screenshot?

Comment: It looks the same on firefox, chrome, and explorer to me. http://tinypic.com/r/2nvcljq/6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to replace current `#footer ul.navigation` rule with this one

```
#footer ul.navigation {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    line-height: 24px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
}
```

Fiddle's and your page's footer don't look the same though.

Comment: You're welcome. But fix what [Tieson T.](http://stackoverflow.com/users/534109/tieson-t) mentioned and of course accept answer...

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look correct to me:

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="about.html">About</a><a href="gallery.html"> Gallery</a>
        <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I would assume if a list was intended to be used, the markup should look like this:

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a><a href="gallery.html"> Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you too! I don't know why it was like that but I changed it.

Comment: @user2150599 You commented on Branislav's answer that his suggestion worked. You should probably mark his as the answer if it actually fixed the issue. You are welcome, regardless.